# mysql connection number over 500

Tags: mysql

We have over 500 processes in our service server, and each of them will keep a mysql connection to the mysql server.
If we keep over 500 connections to mysql server at the same time, is it going to affect the performance of mysql?

In my opinion, the performance won't be affect, since mysql server will keep a connection pool, and response to service server when there is a sql request.
For our situation, we will have a connection pool over 500, and I don't think 500 will be too much for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your configuration, but I know that this can be bad. If all connections are closed propper this won't be a problem, but If not it can happen that your server won't accept more connections until a timeout is reached which would result a big delay for your clients. If possible pool the connection on the client site too, this is always a good idea, so you don't need to wait that the tcp connection is established and the auth and so on.

Comment: our mysql server's max connection is 1000, so we should have enough connection for new connect.

Comment: What is your usecase? A website?

Comment: website, but front-end code don't connect to mysql directly, but through service server. So we can suppose our mysql server will only have 500 connection.

Comment: The problem is: Is there signify performance difference for mysql to keep 50 connections and 500 connections?